# While debugging with lldb a macOS application, is it possible to watch the contents of a register for changes with a watchpoint?

Tags: c, objective-c, swift, macos, lldb

While debugging with lldb a macOS application, is it possible to watch the contents of a register for changes with a watchpoint ? I mean not the memory to which the address contained in the register points to, but the contents of the register itself, for example from 0x000000000 to 0x000000001 ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to get the processor to trap when a particular register changes value.  In any case, not one that lldb has access to.

Short of that, you'd have to instruction-single-step and check the value on each stop.  That would work, but will be pretty slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I understand that you are an expert and you are correct. Nevertheless, from my little experience, it is very surprising that that is not possible. Thanks a lot anyway. Would something scripting related work ?

Comment: The watch related features on most processors watch buses going into the CPU (instruction & memory) but not for instance moving one register into another.  Intervening there would take a huge performance hit.  There are trace facilities on most CPU's that can be used to record register values.  But those don't generally look at values, they just record, so they can go fast enough.

Comment: You can use either an external Python scripted runner, or a scripted thread plan, to get the debugger to instruction single step one or more threads, checking register values as you go.  That is doable, and not even all that hard.  But the app you are debugging will run VERY VERY slowly.  So much so that if it's a UI app you probably won't be able to interact with it meaningfully...  But if you don't have any other way to solve your problem, can script your app's interactions, and have a couple of days to wait, this is a viable method.